# Write the geometric progression equation

Tags: logarithms, recreational-mathematics, geometric-progressions

There is a sequence whose elements have the following dependency

```
a[i] = (a[i-1] + 2 * a[i-1] * Sqrt(2)) / 2
a[i=1] = 10
```

I need to write a sequence equation and find `a[i=5]`

Simplifying the expression, I obtained a dependence equation of the following form

```
a[i] = a[i-1]*(1/2)*(1 + 2 * Sqrt(2)) = a[i-1] * some_constant
```

Therefore, this function is a [geometric progression (Wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression), the general equation of which is

```
a[n] = a[1] * r^(n-1)
```

Using brute force, I calculated the `a[i=5]` element and, accordingly, knowing the general equation, I determined the value `r = 1.91421356`. For different `a[i=1]` the value of `r` remains the same.
But I still don’t understand how to get `r` value from `1/2 * (1 + 2 * Sqrt(2))`.

So my question is as follows: How to convert `1/2, 1, 2 and Sqrt(2)` to `r = 1.91421356`?

**Thanks in advance to all participants!**

PS: This problem arose when I was solving an issue with rotating squares and piling them on top of each other (in programming). I understand that the solution is simple, but I can't wrap my head around it. Initial values such as a[i=1]=10 and a[i=5] are given for convenience.

I don't know how to add a comment so that it can be easily read. Therefore, the answer to the comment was added to the question

@peterwhy Thanks for your response. This is how I calculated:

```
a[i = 1] = 10
a[i = 2] = 19.14213562373095
a[i = 3] = 36.64213562373095
a[i = 4] = 70.14087296526012
a[i = 5] = 134.26461030678928

a[n] = a[1]*r^(n-1)
r = (a[n] / a[1])^(1/(n-1))
```

For example, lets take `i = 4`

```
a[n]/a[1] = (70.14087296526012/10) = 7.014087...
```

then

```
r = 7.014087^(1/3) = 1.9142135353981375 (with rounding error)
```

Comment: In particular for $n=2$, $a[2] = a[1] \cdot r^{2-1} = a[1] \cdot \frac12 \left(1+\sqrt 2\right)$, so (since $a[1]\ne 0$) you can match $r = \frac12\left(1+\sqrt 2\right)$.

Comment: But for why $r = \frac12\left(1+\sqrt 2\right)$ would become "$r = 1.91421356$", I am not sure.

Comment: $a[2]$ would be `a[2] = (10 + 10 * Sqrt(2)) / 2 = 12.07...`, right?

Comment: Yes, of course, you are right. It was me, a blind id**t, who wrote one equation in code and made a mistake on this website. The error has been corrected. Also added my calculations. Thank you @peterwhy!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @peterwhy, the solution was much simpler. You just need to equate `r` to the expression `r = (1 + 2 * sqrt(2)) / 2`